# Updates and Self Joins and Case Statements - oh my

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-workbench, self-join, case-statement

I think I may be trying to do too much with one query, and it's been driving me batty.

I have two tables, Source and Zip_Code. The Source table has a zip code field that can either be 3 or 5 digits.

If it's 3 digits, I need to join to the zip_code table's 3-digit field and set the Source's new_zip field to the zip_code table's corresponding 5-digit entry.

If it's 5 digits, I need to link to the zip_code table's 5-digit field (to make sure it's a valid zip code), then put that 5-digit number in the Source's new_zip field.

I already understand that you can't manipulate something you're updating, hence using a self-join to manipulate a copy. So now I need to create Source2, and join Source1, Source2, and Zip_Code tables.

```
UPDATE SOURCE1
INNER JOIN SOURCE2 ON SOURCE1_UID = SOURCE2_UID
INNER JOIN ZIP_CODE ON SOURCE1_ZIP =
   (   
    SELECT
      (
       CASE WHEN LENGTH(SOURCE1.ZIP <4
       THEN ZIP_CODE.3_DIGIT
       ELSE ZIP_CODE.5_DIGIT
       END
       )
    FROM SOURCE2
    ) 

SET SOURCE1.NEW_ZIP = 
 (
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(SOURCE1.ZIP <4
  THEN ZIP_CODE.3_DIGIT
  ELSE ZIP_CODE.5_DIGIT
  END
  )
```

I know I'm doing something majorly wrong, but I'm having a block as to where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not naming the `Source` table in the query. You need to name the table and then give it an alias like `Source1` if you have to refer to it twice.

But I don't think there's any need for the self-join.

There's no need for the subqueries, you can use conditionals in an `ON` clause.

```
UPDATE Source AS s
JOIN Zip_Code AS z ON 
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(s.zip) = 3
        THEN z.3_digit
        ELSE z.5_digit
    END
SET s.new_zip = z.5_digit
```

Your description says that you always want to set `new_zip` to the 5-digit code, so there's no need for a `CASE` in the `SET` clause.